# Probability that binomial random variable is greater than another

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with respective distributions $B(n+1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $B(n,\frac{1}{2})$. I am trying to determine $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$. So far, I have written that:

$$\mathbb{P}(X>Y)=\sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X>k)\mathbb{P}(Y=k)=\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\sum_{j=k+1}^{n+1}{n+1 \choose j}.$$
However, at this point, I am not sure how to compute the double sum involving the binomial coefficients. Is there any way we can re-arrange the terms to make use of the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}=2^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)=2^{-2n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{n+1\choose j} $$
by the same argument as in your question.

Now let $l=n-k$ and $i=n+1-j$, so that ${n\choose k}={n\choose l}$ and ${n+1\choose j}={n+1\choose i}$.

If $0\leq j\leq k$ then $n+1-k\leq n+1-j\leq n+1$, i.e. $l+1\leq i\leq n+1$. Therefore
$$ \mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)=2^{-2n-1}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\sum_{j=0}^{k}{n+1\choose j}=2^{-2n-1}\sum_{l=0}^n{n\choose l}\sum_{i=l+1}^{n+1}{n+1\choose i}=\mathbb{P}(X>Y) $$

Since the events $\{X\leq Y\}$ and $\{X>Y\}$ are complementary, each must have probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

Alicia and Beti each toss a fair coin repeatedly. Alicia does it $n+1$ times and Beti does it $n$ times. Alicia wins if her number $X$ of heads is **greater** than Beti's number $Y$ of heads.

We find the probability that $X\gt Y$, that is, the probability that Alicia wins.

After $n$ tosses by Alicia, and $n$ by Beti, there are three possibilities:

(i) Alicia is leading. Then, whatever happens on her $(n+1)$-th toss, Alicia will win

(ii) Beti is leading. Then whatever happens on Alicia's $(n+1)$-th toss, Beti will win.

(iii) They are tied. Then, depending on the result of her $(n+1)$-th toss, Alicia will win or lose.

By symmetry (i) and (ii) are equally likely. And in Case (iii), Alicia has probability $1/2$ of winning.

Thus the probability that Alicia wins the game is $1/2$.  So $\Pr(X\gt Y)=1/2$.

Comment: This is actually where my problem comes from! But I am trying to prove it via the brute force approach to improve my manipulation of binomial sums

Comment: @user223935: One can translate the probabilistic argument into a sum argument, by splitting the double sum into three parts (i), (ii), (iii) as in the answer above.  Then it would *look* like a summation manipulation, but there would be no gain, since the intuition for the rearrangement would come from elsewhere.